# Parse error as I write a church number using Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here, it is the source code to output church number. As I compiler, it occurs an error message:

parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

I have no idea. Anyone can help? Thanks

```
module Main where

type Church a = (a -> a) -> a -> a

church :: Integer -> Church Integer
church 0 = \f -> \x -> x
church n = \f -> \x -> f (church (n-1) f x)

let r = church 0  
main = print (r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` is used in expressions and `do` notation; to define a binding at the module level, drop the `let`:

```
r = church 0  
main = print r
```

Even after this change, though, you'll get an error, since `r` has type `Church Integer`, aka `(Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer`, a function. Unfortunately, functions aren't `show`able, and thus aren't `print`able. If you wanted to display the number inside, you could use

```
r = church 0  
main = print (r succ 0)
```

Comment: It occurs other errors:

No instance for (Show (Church Integer)) arising from a use of `print' Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Church Integer)) In the expression: print r In an equation for `main': main = print r

Comment: Thank you very much. It's success !